# Why does Spliterator<?> defines NONNULL as a characteristic?

Tags: java, null, java-8, java-stream

The [javadoc of `Spliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) (which is basically what is really behind a `Stream` if I understand things correctly) defines many characeristics which make sense such as `SIZED`, `CONCURRENT`, `IMMUTABLE` etc.

But it also defines [`NONNULL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#NONNULL); why?

I'd have though that it would be the user's responsibility to ensure that and that if, for instance, a developer tried to `.sort()` a non `SORTED` stream where there are null elements he/she would rightfully be greeted with an NPE...

But then this characteristic exists. Why? The javadoc of `Spliterator` itself doesn't mention any real usage of it, and neither does the `package-info.java` of the `java.util.stream` package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `Spliterator`:

> A Spliterator also reports a set of `characteristics()` of its structure, source, and elements from among `ORDERED`, `DISTINCT`, `SORTED`, `SIZED`, `NONNULL`, `IMMUTABLE`, `CONCURRENT`, and `SUBSIZED`. These may be employed by Spliterator clients to control, specialize or simplify computation.

Note that it does *not* mention the prevention of `NullPointerException`s. If you sort a `Stream` which might contain `null` values it *is* your responsibility to provide a `Comparator` which can handle `null`s.

The second sentence also makes it clear that using these flags is only an option, not a requirement for “Spliterator clients”, which is not limited to usage by `Stream`s.

---

So regardless of whether it is used by the current implementation of the `Stream` API, are there possibilities to gain advantage of the knowledge about a `NONULL` characteristic?

I think so. An implementation may branch to a specialized code for a non-`null` `Spliterator` to utilize `null` for representing certain state then, e.g. absent values or the initial value before processing the first element, etc. If fact, the actual implementation code for dealing with `Stream`s which may contain `null` *is* complicated. But of course, you always have to weigh up whether the simplification of one case justifies the code duplication.

But sometimes the simplification is as simple as knowing that there are no `null` values implies that you can use one of the `Concurrent…` Collections, which don’t allow `null`s, internally.

Comment: Hmmwait... Aren't `Stream`s the primary clients here? I'm probably too narrow minded but I don't see what other clients you could possibly devise. Sure, you can implement your own (I did that), but other than using it in a `Stream`...

Comment: Isn’t “you can implement your own” a strong point, if not *the* point of the Java API, which is there to support you in writing your own application rather than providing complete applications? Besides that, `Stream`s are the primary clients, yes, but that is not limited to the *current implementation* of `Stream`s. Adding a new characteristic in a future version would require a major release, but adding an implementation which makes (better) use of an already existing flag may happen in every little update. So it’s a reasonable strategy to add flags with potential value as early as possible.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's a strong point; I guess I'm just not knowledgeable enough about the design decisions behind it :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the following comments in the code for the enum `StreamOpFlag`.

```
// The following Spliterator characteristics are not currently used but a
// gap in the bit set is deliberately retained to enable corresponding
// stream flags if//when required without modification to other flag values.
//
// 4, 0x00000100 NONNULL(4, ...
// 5, 0x00000400 IMMUTABLE(5, ...
// 6, 0x00001000 CONCURRENT(6, ...
// 7, 0x00004000 SUBSIZED(7, ...
```

Comment: Uh, even `IMMUTABLE` and `CONCURRENT`? How is parallelization decided then? The more it goes, the more I'm confused :/